# Capslock started to switch the language, but is not set to do so. How to disable it?

Tags: keyboard, language-support, capslock

My Ubuntu 20.04 started writing in capitals. Capslock changes a language.

In Settings -> Keyboard, I do not have this set. The language change is set to Super + space, however when I go to Languages -> Installed inputs I see capslock listed as one of the language switching keys.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. It is probably specific to some Lenovo models like my T540p.

Since it was out of the blue, I thought it must have been some accidental keyboard shortcut. I kept trying, until I found:

I have pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Capslock</kbd> by accident, which does not have any visual response in the system or on the laptop (Lenovo T540p), but starts this behavior (I guess it's supposed to be a "Caps-lock lock", but also sends a wrong code for the Caps Lock key to the system).

Pressing that again toggled it off.

Answer (score 0):

"Out of the blue" sounds odd. Anyway, on Ubuntu you can probably fix it using this command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```